# SQL select values from joined table where value and value appears

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL tables:

- station (id, name)
- station_track (id, id_station, id_track)
- track (id, name)

and I'd like to get all the tracks that contains station A and station B... I just can't figure it out :S I tried like this:

```
SELECT track.name
FROM track, station_track , station 
 WHERE station.id = station_track.id_station 
  AND track.id = station_track.id_track 
  AND (station.name = 'first' AND station.name = 'second')
```

It doesn't work... I guess I can't use AND for same column values.

SOLVED:

```
SELECT proge.ime FROM postaje, postaje_proge, proge
WHERE postaje.id=postaje_proge.ID_postaje AND proge.ID=postaje_proge.ID_proge 
AND postaje.ime_postaje in ("AP Mlinska","City Center")
GROUP BY proge.ime
HAVING count(proge.ime)=2
```

tnxx guys for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want tracks linked to both stations A and B, try:

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM track t
JOIN station_track st on t.id=st.id_track 
JOIN station s on s.id=st.id_station and s.name in ('first','second')
GROUP BY t.name
HAVING count(distinct s.name)=2
```

Comment: @user2433018: Are you sure there are any tracks linked to both stations? Can you add some sample data to the question? This should work.

Comment: here is the database...i hope it helps... http://pastebin.com/vYpmDnVb

and your answer changed into my names...
SELECT proge.ime 
FROM proge
JOIN postaje_proge on proge.ID=postaje_proge.ID_proge 
JOIN postaje on postaje.id=postaje_proge.ID_proge and postaje.ime_postaje in ('Ptujska - Pošta','Ptujska - TAM')
GROUP BY proge.ime
HAVING count(proge.ime)=2

Answer (score 3):

Your final condition, `(station.name="first" AND station.name="second")`, is checking that one variable is equal to two different values at the same time which will never evaluate to true.

If you want to find all stations with the names `first` or `second`, you need to use an `OR` statement.

```
SELECT track.name FROM track, station_track , station 
WHERE station.id=station_track.id_station 
AND track.id=station_track.id_track 
AND (station.name="first" OR station.name="second")
```

Comment: +1 It's also unrelated to the stated objective - to "get all tracks that contains station A and station B".

Comment: ok :D i get that now...so how to make it work? any idea? :D i dont know a lot of SQL but it would be nice to solve problem with SQL..as alternative i was thinking to change that AND to OR and compare results in c# after...but it would be nicer to solve it in SQL so i dont need to transfer so much data :D

Comment: hehe i dont want this OR that....i need this AND that (imagine bus lines...u know one buss line have like 100 stations...and now i need to get all bus lines that have station A and station B on it... )

Comment: To understand why `OR` is the only way that statement returns all of the rows you're looking for, you need to understand the way the query is processed. Each row is processed and tested against the conditions you give it. If you use `station.name="first" AND station.name="second"`, each row is going to return false because the column can't have 2 different values. When you use `station.name="first" OR station.name="second"`, each row is compared to see whether it is one of the two provided. If so, it's added to the return result.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a bit of thinking and redesign your tables. If you want to match a field to a list of values you can use the 'in' operative

i.e

```
SELECT * FROM station_track WHERE id_track in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

The above will return all records matching any of the values in the list. So, think about how you could take advantage of this and redesign your schema.

Comment: SELECT proge.ime FROM postaje, postaje_proge, proge
WHERE postaje.id=postaje_proge.ID_postaje AND proge.ID=postaje_proge.ID_proge 
AND postaje.ime_postaje in ("AP Mlinska","Melje - obračališče")

returns same as OR clause...i dont want result with only one station(postaje) i want just that with both...